# Alternative to `unwrap()` when `T` does not implement `Debug`

Tags: rust, unwrap

I am aware that `x.unwrap()` when `x: Result<T, E>` does not work when `E` does not implement `Debug`: `unwrap()` would need to print out the `Err` variant in case `x.is_err()` but it cannot. Sometimes, however, especially in tests, I do need to get my hands on the `Ok` value. I assumed `x.expect()` would do the trick, as I am the one that specifies the message upon failure. And yet, for some reason I don't completely understand, `expect()`, too, requires `E: Debug`. This means that I always end up taking the verbose, repetitive way:

```
   let x_ok = match x {
      Ok(x_ok) => x_ok,
      Err(_) => panic!("Something went horribly wrong!"),
   }
```

I cannot imagine there wouldn't be a more standardised solution to this problem, and yet I struggle to find one. How does one quickly `get_ok_or_panic` if the `Err` type of a `Result` does not implement `Debug`?

Comment: Not really different than the existing answers but alternative: `x.map_err(|_| "Something went horribly wrong!").unwrap();`

Comment: The proper solution would be to make `E` implement `Debug`; or even better, [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html), which implies `Debug`. Every error of every library I know does that, and I recommend doing it as well. To define errors properly, use [`thiserror`](https://docs.rs/thiserror); this is pretty much the standard everywhere. Having errors that don't implement `Debug` is a code smell to me.

Comment: @Finomnis It's not necessarily about a concrete error that doesn't implement `Debug`. This issue tends to appear in generic code - for example, you might require `T: FromStr` and want to use `x.parse().unwrap()`. In that case it can be a hassle to also require `<T as FromStr>::Err: Debug`, especially if that requirement has to infect other traits and associated types, some of which you might not control.

Comment: `expect()` also prints the error, alongside with the message.

Comment: Makes sense; I'd still argue that `<T as FromStr>::Err: Error` is a sane type bound that is fine to use in generic code. At least if you use it to `panic`, it should at least be printable. Otherwise it would be silently swallowed and discarded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idiomatic code would just forward the error:

```rust
fn do_it() -> Result<(), E> {
   let x_ok = x_ok?;
   // work with x_ok
   Ok(())
}
```

or handle the error gracefully where possible:

```rust
let x_ok = x_ok.unwrap_or(sane_default);
```

If neither is an option and you absolutely have to panic you can use `let … else`:

```rust
let Ok(x_ok) = x_ok else { panic!("Something went horribly wrong") };
```

Comment: Of course, of course, one should handle errors, but as far as I'm given to understand it is common practice, for example, to use `unwrap()` in tests, where `panic()`ing is an indicator of a test having failed. Am I correct saying this? I didn't know of the `let ... else` syntax, thank you for showing me!

Comment: Test's can return `Result` too with an `Err` variant signalling a test failure.

Answer (score 5):

The typical workaround is to use [`unwrap_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else):

```
let x_ok = x.unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Something went horribly wrong!"));
```

Comment: I'd only use `unwrap_or_else` in a case I can provide a sane alternative, not to panic. Unless of course you're targeting old Rust versions as well.

Comment: @cafce25 Duly noted, but that is your personal preference - panicking in `unwrap_or_else()` is both reasonable and commonplace, particularly when the panic is lexically visible, as is the case here.